# Класс java может содержать лишь один такой элемент

Tags: java, ооп, классы, методы, переменные

Читаю книгу Head First Java. И ответ на один вопрос показался мне очень странным. Ниже картинка.

Разве в классе Java может быть только одна переменная экземпляра? Такой же вопрос с остальными частями ответа.

Может я что-то недопонял?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с неправильным переводом. В оригинале вопрос звучит так:
A class can have any numbers of these.   instance variables, getter, setter,method